# springboot application doesn't start with postgres connection

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am new to springboot and postgres and trying to connect those. My application starts very well. From the logs it indicate that Spring Boot application is starting successfully and initializing the JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit, but it seems to shut down immediately after starting. Not sure the exact reason.

Providing all the details below.

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbname
spring.datasource.username=username

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

Model

**Product.java**

```
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Entity
public class Product {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String sku;
    private String name;
    
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getSku() {
        return sku;
    }

    public void setSku(String sku) {
        this.sku = sku;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**Logs**

```
2023-10-29T01:25:19.851+04:00  INFO 78086 --- [           main] c.s.s.SpringDataJpaCourseApplication     : Starting SpringDataJpaCourseApplication using Java 17.0.7 with PID 78086 (/Users/keerthana/Downloads/spring-data-jpa-course/target/classes started by keerthana in /Users/keerthana/Downloads/spring-data-jpa-course)
2023-10-29T01:25:19.853+04:00  INFO 78086 --- [           main] c.s.s.SpringDataJpaCourseApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-10-29T01:25:20.043+04:00  INFO 78086 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-10-29T01:25:20.052+04:00  INFO 78086 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 5 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-10-29T01:25:20.206+04:00  INFO 78086 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-10-29T01:25:20.234+04:00  INFO 78086 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.2.13.Final
2023-10-29T01:25:20.235+04:00  INFO 78086 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000406: Using bytecode reflection optimizer
2023-10-29T01:25:20.363+04:00  INFO 78086 --- [           main] o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo      : No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
2023-10-29T01:25:20.376+04:00  INFO 78086 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-10-29T01:25:20.441+04:00  INFO 78086 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@74f827ad
2023-10-29T01:25:20.442+04:00  INFO 78086 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-10-29T01:25:20.467+04:00  WARN 78086 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000025: PostgreSQLDialect does not need to be specified explicitly using 'hibernate.dialect' (remove the property setting and it will be selected by default)
2023-10-29T01:25:20.832+04:00  INFO 78086 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000489: No JTA platform available (set 'hibernate.transaction.jta.platform' to enable JTA platform integration)
Hibernate: 
    drop table if exists product cascade
2023-10-29T01:25:20.842+04:00  WARN 78086 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Warning Code: 0, SQLState: 00000
2023-10-29T01:25:20.842+04:00  WARN 78086 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : table "product" does not exist, skipping
Hibernate: 
    create table product (
        id bigint not null,
        name varchar(255),
        sku varchar(255),
        primary key (id)
    )
2023-10-29T01:25:20.874+04:00  INFO 78086 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-10-29T01:25:20.933+04:00  INFO 78086 --- [           main] c.s.s.SpringDataJpaCourseApplication     : Started SpringDataJpaCourseApplication in 1.249 seconds (process running for 1.5)
2023-10-29T01:25:20.935+04:00  INFO 78086 --- [ionShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-10-29T01:25:20.936+04:00  INFO 78086 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2023-10-29T01:25:20.938+04:00  INFO 78086 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**pom.xml**

```
<properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

My application doesn't run after this.
Please let me know what went wrong here.

Comment: Can you add the `spring-boot` version?

Comment: can you share `pom.xml` file ?